# Secure Web forms for payment

Tags: security

there probably plenty of you here who have done secure payment forms in their life, so am i. My question is general what from your experience is "more right" way to process these forms. I'm not talking about SSL or server based security but about programming itself using pseudo code ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides having the page protected with valid certificate and SSL, 
You need to validate all field, use parameters when sending the data, check for Injections of any kinds, and try to use an many listbox as possible and as little free texts..

thats my 2 cents on payment security.

If you want to protect your site from phishing attacks - you should also use some anti-phishing mechanism (like a personalized pictures)

and to protect against bots (very annoying) use captcha....

Comment: What does personalized pictures mean ?
Don't you think captcha damages form's accessibility. I know plenty of 30+ years old with little knowledge in internet for whom captcha on secure form may seem like a puzzle so i will end up with loss of 30%-60% ( depends on product type )

Comment: Personalized picture is advanced technique - not for random access user but for returning one, it is used by banks.
about captcha - to avoid this problems one should use a simple clear captcha and not a psychedelic one... even a simple 4 letters jpg can do the work in most cases.